# Showing that a function is Darboux Integrable using definition of integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I have been given a function $f:[0, 4]→ \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ne 2$ and $f(2) = 2$, and told to show that $f$ is Darboux integrable in $[0,4]$.
However, I don't understand how a function like this can be integrable, as it is mostly a constant function that equals $0$ and then a single disconnected point at $(2, 2)$. How is this function meant to be integrable?

Comment: That's precisely the point. $f$ is constant except for a single point, which is what makes it integrable

Comment: @peek-a-boo My understanding of integrability is that there is some area under a curve that is meant to be calculated, I don't understand how there could be an area to calculate with the function provided

Comment: The term "area under a curve" is not precise at all. Such a phrase only has meaning only if we decide to give it one, and the definition of Riemann/Darboux integrability allows us to give meaning to "area under a curve" even for discontinuous functions (btw if you have access to Spivak's Calculus book, I highly suggest you read Chapter 13 on integrals; it helped me tremendously). Anyway, what is the definition of Darboux integrability? Have you proved the equivalent statement that $f$ is integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a partition such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$?

Comment: like peek-a-boo says, you should edit the question to include the definition of "Darboux integrable."  This way, we will know what exactly about $f$ you want to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{\mathcal P_n\}$ be a sequence of partitions of $[0,4]$ such that $\operatorname{gap}\mathcal P_n \rightarrow 0$

It is trivial to show that $\mathcal L(f,\mathcal P_n) = 0$ for any $n$. Then, you just need to show that $\mathcal U(f,\mathcal P_n) \rightarrow 0$, which you can do by using the fact that $\mathcal U(f,\mathcal P_n) \le 2 \cdot \operatorname{gap}\mathcal P_n$.